# Is there a better way using nested listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, nested-lists, flutter-listview

I want to design a page where multiple listview builders are used horiz.

Can anyone suggest me the better way or using the nested effect the performance of the app.

This is the desired design i want to make

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use slivers for performance to work with multiple listview builders
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/scrolling/slivers

for more detail

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0